# Disabling the "Loading many items" dialog in Sitecore Rocks

Tags: sitecore-rocks

In `Sitecore Rocks` when you open a folder in the `Media Library` that has more than 100 items, you'll get the "Loading many items" dialog to ask you if you want to load it all or only the top 100.

I've never had a problem with `VS` when loading all the items so I'd like to suppress this dialog, is there any way of doing this?

Possibly using a config patch file?

I've checked all the options available in `Tools > Options > Sitecore` but none are related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed that this is hardcoded in a couple locations of Rocks:

- [`ItemTreeViewItem`](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/blob/master/src/Sitecore.Rocks/ContentTrees/Items/ItemTreeViewItem.cs#L476)
- [`MyItemsTreeViewItemBase`](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/blob/master/src/Sitecore.Rocks/ContentTrees/VirtualItems/MyItems/MyItemsTreeViewItemBase.cs#L40)

It's a rather unfriendly message though and with proper use of async I would think that we could avoid making Visual Studio "grumpy" and the need for this message at all. Perhaps some pagination instead, though UX-wise that's hard to do in a tree. At the very least, that 100-item limit could be made configurable.

This would be a good candidate for an [enhancement request](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Rocks/issues) and of course a PR if you are feeling inclined.